# How do I make chrome.tabs.onUpdated work on an inactive tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using this injection script on a chrome extension's background code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tab) {
    // for the current tab, inject the "inject.js" file & execute it
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.ib, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    });
});
```

`inject.js` basically says reload the page every 5 seconds if the page matches a certain URL.

The idea is that the page loads, injects the script, then reloads itself and so on to form an auto reloader of some sort.

The only problem with this is that the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` event only fires on an active tab.

How to make the script also work on inactive tabs so it reloads itself?

Comment: onUpdated fires on any updated tab so there's something else in your code that restricts it to the active tab. Also, depending on inject.js expectations you may want to check `tab.status == 'complete'` first.

Comment: `tab.ib` should be `tab`. The [first argument for the listener is just the integer `tabId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-onUpdated-tabId).

Comment: This is not working because of the typo I mentioned above. You are always passing `undefined`. [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) defaults to [the active tab in the current window when you don't pass a tabId](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-executeScript-tabId).